# In a leaflet map, popup (created as a L.Handler) not showing when loading a big JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have some data that I display using a layer.
I want to dynamically display these data on mouse hover, in a popup.

The popup will be shown next to the mouse pointer.
The popup will follow the cursor and will dynamically display the layer's data relative to the position of the mouse pointer.

The problem:

It works well in general, but when I load a lot af data, the popup does not appear. But if the user moves the mouse pointer outside the viewport and then moves the mouse pointer inside the viewport again, then the popup is displayed. Obviously it's not user-friendly :-) , so I would like the popup to be displayed even when I load a lot of data.

I've tried different ways to create a popup, used jQuery `$(document).ready` to be sure data have been loded, etc. but none of these works. I'm running out of ideas. But it seems that it has to do with the time spent by the browser to load the data.
Could someone help me to solve this problem ?

Notes: depending on the amount of data, it sometimes works in Chrome but never in Firefox.

Here is a reproducible example and a script to generate the `data.js` file.

The HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #map {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Loading "big" data -->
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Create a cursor handler
        // In order to display informations in a popup next to cursor
        // (the popup will follow the mouse pointer) 
        L.CursorHandler = L.Handler.extend({
            addHooks: function() {
                this._popup = new L.Popup({ autoPan: false });
                this._map.on('mouseover', this._open, this);
                this._map.on('mousemove', this._update, this);
                this._map.on('mouseout', this._close, this);
            },

            removeHooks: function() {
                this._map.off('mouseover', this._open, this);
                this._map.off('mousemove', this._update, this);
                this._map.off('mouseout', this._close, this);
            },

            _open: function(e) {
                this._update(e);
                this._popup.openOn(this._map);
            },

            _close: function() {
                this._map.closePopup(this._popup);
            },

            _update: function(e) {
                var text_to_display = "Data";
                this._popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(text_to_display);
            }
        });

        L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'cursor', L.CursorHandler);

        // Create map
        var map = L.map("map", { zoom: 6, center: [0, 0] });

        // To enable popup display next to cursor
        map.cursor.enable();

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script to generate the js file containing the data:

The real data is an array of objects and arrays.
This script will produce a file of 100 MB (since it seems that it has to do with the time spent by the browser to load the data).
It's a 100 MB file to be sure it will be reproductible. My tests showned that with a 5MB file, sometimes the popup is displayed, and sometimes not. With a file of 10 MB, no popup 90% of the time. With a 100MB file, no popup 100% of the time.

In Python:

```
# Create a 100 MB file
big_string = '1234567890' * 10000000
javascript_variable = 'var data = "' + big_string + '";'

with open("data.js", "w") as f:
    f.write(javascript_variable)
```

In JS:

```
big_string = '1234567890'.repeat(10000000)
javascript_variable = 'var data = "' + big_string + '";'
// Then copy-paste the object in a "data.js" file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can prevent this if you add in the `_update` function a check if the popup is open:

```
_update: function(e) {
        var text_to_display = "Data";
        this._popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(text_to_display);
        if(!this._popup.isOpen()){
          this._popup.openOn(this._map);
        }
      }
```

And I recommand to add this options to the popup, so it should not close when you click on the map.

```
this._popup = new L.Popup({ autoPan: false, autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false });
```

Comment: the `_update()` function is called everytime you move the mous. So the popup will opened when you move the mouse. I think because of the long loading the `mouseover` is not called correctly and then the popup is not opened